# Converting a sequence of numbers to a set in VBA ACCESS

Tags: vba, ms-access, set

I would like all the numbers from 1 to 1000000 to be put into a set in VBA Access for example, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ..., 1000000} How can I do this? I need all the numbers to be in this set format so that I can perform set operations with all of those numbers.

I would like to perform set operations like subtracting a list from a list like:

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, ..., 1000000}- {1, 2, 3}= {4, 5, 6, 7, 8,..., 1000000}

But I need a clever way of getting all the numbers from one to 1000000 as a set.

Comment: Put them in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for an array. You'll need to rebuild it with various reductions as you describe, but it should do what you need.

```
Sub MakeArray()
Dim myArray(1 To 1000000) As Long

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    myArray(i) = i
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do I need to specify i though? Why can't I just put the first two rows of your code and then perform the operations I want with myArray.

Comment: @Ruva The two lines that start with `Dim` define the type of variables you are setting up.  In general this is a best practice to writing code, particularly with vba and arrays.  The array doesn't have numeric values until it loops through all elements. Also, make sure to click `accept` to answers that address your problem. I glanced at your profile and it appears you've asked 12 questions yet none have been accepted.